# Extract number from txt file and use as jquery variable to incrementally increase circle

Tags: php, jquery, scale, click-counting

I need a circle to grow every time a button is cumulatively clicked, which means it needs to be server stored and not locally stored.
As of now, I have managed to count the clicks via this php code, which stores in a .txt file the amount of times the button has been clicked:

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['clicks']) ) { 
    incrementClickCount();
}

function getClickCount()
{
    return (int)file_get_contents("clickit.txt");
}

function incrementClickCount()
{
    $count = getClickCount() + 1;
    file_put_contents("clickit.txt", $count);
}

?>
```

I would like to extract the number in the clickit.txt and use it to increment, with jquery, the size of a circle via css.

```js
var numberClicks = ${'#number-clicks', 'value'}

$('.main-circle').css('width', 'numberClicks', 'vw')
```

```css
.main-circle {
    position: fixed;
    width: 1vw;
    height: 1vw;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

```html
<div class="main-circle"></div>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="neuer erfolg" name="clicks">
    </form>
    <div>Click Count: <span id="number-clicks"<?php echo getClickCount(); ?> </div>
```

I know this doesn't work as is, but I can't figure out the correct syntax.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Just load the cumulative click count with your main page load as the value for your jQuery. `<script>let clickCount = <?php echo getClickCount(); ?>;</script>` and let your jQuery take it from there. Or if you must use the `span`, then add a data-attribute `data-clicks` and get that. Or put it inside the span and get the element's `innerText`. There is no _value_ to a span. Since you're not doing this async but are actually submitting the form, no need to make it complicated.